# Getting errors after using Layout Builder

Tags: debugging

The rest of the site works as expected.

This is the error I get when trying to access content from the http://barrio.local/admin/content link.

```
Warning: Undefined array key 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\apps\barrio\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Utility\Error.php on line 142
Warning: Undefined array key "file" in C:\xampp\htdocs\apps\barrio\web\core\includes\errors.inc on line 77
Warning: Undefined array key "line" in C:\xampp\htdocs\apps\barrio\web\core\includes\errors.inc on line 78
```

The file `\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Utility\Error.php line 142` is

```
$call = $backtrace[0];
```

The file `\core\includes\errors.inc line 77 & 78` is

```
'%file' => $caller['file'],
'%line' => $caller['line'],
```

Is there an answer to this problem?

Comment: An exception occurs but Drupal's own exception handler is not finding required information about the exception to properly log and render an error message.

Comment: This is Installation Problem of other module https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3345713 Try this one may be solve your problem
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3345713#comment-14951651